# Comparing item with all other items in the same variable using for-loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a matrix of data that compares children's productions of a word token with their production of other word tokens. So, for example, in the following sample dataset, I want to compare "tedi" in row 1 with each other form in the `Actual` column.

```
 library(tibble) 
  production.data <- tribble(~Subject, ~Age, ~Target, ~Actual,
       "subj1", "001126", "teddy", "tedi",
       "subj1", "001126", "teddy", "dedi",
       "subj1", "001126", "daddy", "dadi",
       "subj1", "001126", "daddy", "didi",
       "subj1", "001126", "daddy", "dati",
       "subj1", "001126", "baby", "beibi",
       "subj1", "001126", "Tigger", "tedi",
       "subj1", "001126", "doggy", "didi",
       "subj1", "001126", "milk", "mi")
```

In another dataset, `values` below, I have a set of values for each consonant/vowel in each word. I want to compare each value for word 1 with each value of all other words in the list (note that the actual `values` dataset is actually a lot bigger than this!).

```
 library(tibble) 
  values <- tribble(~Target, ~Actual, ~C1_Sonorant, ~C1_Consonantal,
       "teddy", "tedi", -1, 1,
       "teddy", "dedi", 1, 1,
       "daddy", "dadi", 1, 1, 
       "daddy", "didi", 1, 1,
       "daddy", "dati", 1, 1, 
       "baby", "beibi", -1, 1,
       "Tigger", "tedi", -1, 1,
       "doggy", "didi", 1, 1,
       "milk", "mi", 0, 0)
```

My question is: How do I get R to do repeated calculations (`C1_Sonorant[1,]-C1_Sonorant[2,]`, `C1_Consonantal[1,]-C1_Consonantal[2,]`) across all rows in the `values` data? I'm quite sure that this will require a for-loop, but I'm not sure how to run cross-variable comparisons in this way.

I think I'd need different matrices for C1_Sonorant, C1_Consonantal, etc., and I expect the output to look something like:

```
 # C1_Sonorant

 output <- tribble(~Target, ~teddy, ~teddy, ~daddy, ~daddy,
       "teddy", 0, -2, -2, -2,
       "teddy", 2, 0, 0, 0,
       "daddy", 2, 0, 0, 0, 
       "daddy", 2, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to compare every row with every row, including itself?

You can do this with a self join (or cross join) as follows. But this probably won't run smoothly with a very big dataset.

```
require(tidyverse)

df1 <- values %>% select(Target1 = Target,
                  Sonorant1 = C1_Sonorant,
                  Consonant1 = C1_Consonantal) %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  group_by(Target1) %>%
  mutate(newname1 = paste(Target1,row_number(),sep = "_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Target1)

df2 <- df1 %>% select(newname2 = newname1,
                      Sonorant2 = Sonorant1,
                      Consonant2 = Consonant1,
                      dummy)

  df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = 'dummy') %>%
    mutate(Son = Sonorant1 - Sonorant2,
           Con = Consonant1 - Consonant2) %>%
    select(newname1,newname2,Son,Con) %>%
    gather(key,value,-newname1,-newname2) %>%
    unite(column,newname2,key) %>%
    spread(column,value)
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 9 x 19
  newname1 baby_1_Con baby_1_Son daddy_1_Con daddy_1_Son daddy_2_Con daddy_2_Son daddy_3_Con daddy_3_Son doggy_1_Con
  <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 baby_1            0          0           0          -2           0          -2           0          -2           0
2 daddy_1           0          2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
3 daddy_2           0          2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
4 daddy_3           0          2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
5 doggy_1           0          2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
6 milk_1           -1          1          -1          -1          -1          -1          -1          -1          -1
7 teddy_1           0          0           0          -2           0          -2           0          -2           0
8 teddy_2           0          2           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
9 Tigger_1          0          0           0          -2           0          -2           0          -2           0
# ... with 9 more variables: doggy_1_Son <dbl>, milk_1_Con <dbl>, milk_1_Son <dbl>, teddy_1_Con <dbl>,
#   teddy_1_Son <dbl>, teddy_2_Con <dbl>, teddy_2_Son <dbl>, Tigger_1_Con <dbl>, Tigger_1_Son <dbl>
```

another option can be:

```
ones <- rep(1,nrow(values))
Son.mat <- values$C1_Sonorant %*% t(ones) - ones %*% t(values$C1_Sonorant)
rownames(Son.mat) <- values$Target
colnames(Son.mat) <- values$Target
Son.Mat
```

gives

```
       teddy teddy daddy daddy daddy baby Tigger doggy milk
teddy      0    -2    -2    -2    -2    0      0    -2   -1
teddy      2     0     0     0     0    2      2     0    1
daddy      2     0     0     0     0    2      2     0    1
daddy      2     0     0     0     0    2      2     0    1
daddy      2     0     0     0     0    2      2     0    1
baby       0    -2    -2    -2    -2    0      0    -2   -1
Tigger     0    -2    -2    -2    -2    0      0    -2   -1
doggy      2     0     0     0     0    2      2     0    1
milk       1    -1    -1    -1    -1    1      1    -1    0
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! I've used the second option as I have to separate out Sonorant vs. Coronal into different matrices, but the first option works with a larger dataset too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding the full scope of what you are trying to do, specifically how your expected output relates to the previous two tasks - like what are each of the values in your expected representing from the first two datasets?

I might be able to offer something for each of the previous tasks individually though.
For the first one, there's a metric called Levenhstein distance that provides metrics of "distance" between two words, see `?adist` for details.

You could apply this to the rows of the first dataset as per the following:

```
apply(production.data, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(r){
adist(r[["Target"]], r[["Actual"]])
})
```

For the second task there's a function from the zoo package to apply a function to a rolling window of observations called rollapply, it could be implemented something like this:

```
zoo::rollapply(values, by.column = F,width = 2, FUN = function(x){
x <- as.data.frame(x)  %>% dplyr::mutate_at(dplyr::vars(dplyr::starts_with("C")), ~ as.numeric(.)) # Since the object is converted to a matrix and it coerces all values to character, convert it to a data.frame and change the numeric values with names starting with C back into numeric.
c(x[1,3, drop = T] - x[2,3, drop = T],# Subtract row 1 C1_sonorant from row 2
x[1,4, drop = T] - x[2,4, drop = T])# Subtract row 1 C1_Consonantal from row 2
})
```

Comment: Thanks for these! I'll have a play around with adist. The `rollapply` option didn't work for me though - it brought up a table with two columns, and all values as NAs. Either that or I get a warning: "Error during wrapup: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?"

Comment: Certainly! Hmm, that's odd that you had that issue with `rollapply` as it worked fine with the example. I'm using zoo 1.8-5 and dplyr 0.7.8, perhaps you're using different versions?
Another guess is that there's unexpected values in those columns in the full dataset that are causing an error. You could test this with the following:
`purrr::map_lgl(values[, stringr::str_detect(names(values),"^C")], ~ all(!is.na(as.numeric(.))))`
This will map over all cols where the name starts with C, coerce the vals to numeric and check to see if all values are not NA. IE, TRUE means all values are numeric